# Laravel:How to get the auto incremented id and send it through the email

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5.3

i want to get the id which is registered last an send that to the admin through email. how can i do that? i tried something like this in Register controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    //dd($data);

    $models = new User;
    $user=User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        /*'usertype' =>$data['usertype'],*/
        'status' => 0,
    ]);
    $use = array('name' => 'Admin');
    //$models->email = Auth::user()->email;
    $message_id = "";
 Mail::send('emailMessage', $use, function ($m) use ($message_id){

      $message_id = Auth::User()->id;


      $m->to('mrbbangladesh2017@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Confirm email');
  });
 return $user;

}
```

Comment: `$user->id` will give the id of the latest user.

Answer (score 0):

To correct your code, you can use the following:

```
Mail::send('emails.registration', ['user' => $user], function ($m) {
    $m->from('admin@app.com', 'App Admin');
    $m->to('admin@app.com', 'App Admin')->subject('Confirm Registration!');
});
```

Then create a view like so:

```
<!-- View stored in resources/views/emails/registration.blade.php -->

A new user, {{ $user->name }} has been registered
```

An alternative way to do the same thing is to use [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events) and fire an event like UserCreated in your controller. This way, you can have multiple listeners to the same events (e.g. if you later want to not only trigger an email to the admin but also do some other actions later, you can just add a listener) or have multiple controllers fire this event (in case there are other ways of registering users)

I would also recommend you use [mail queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#queueing-mail) to reduce your response time